# Plotly.js adding linegraph to barchart makes bars disappear

Tags: javascript, plotly

I have created a barchart that works properly the way I want. Right now, I'm trying to add a linegraph to overlap the bars, but when I run the code, the linegraph appears, but the bars disappear. It seems pretty simple to add the linegraph, but for some reason it's not working. I'm not getting any mistakes in console either.

```
var x_text = ["Comodities","Consumer Discretionary","Utilities",
              "Health & Biotech","Global Real Estate","Financials",
              "Emerging Market Bonds","Technologies","Industrials",
              "Oil & Gas","China Equities","S&P500"];
  //             
  var trace1 = [{ 

    x: x_text, // X axis (names)
    y: zValues, // Values (y axis)
    hoverinfo: zValues, 
    type: 'bar',
    orientation:"v",
    marker: {
    color: color_list, // Color of bars
    line: {
      color: 'rbg(8,48,107)',
      width: 1
    }},
    yauto: false,
    showscale: true,
  }];

  var trace2 = {
  x: x_text,
  y: [-0.1,-0.1,2.3,3.3,1.0,0.4,0.9,3.0,-0.1,-1.4,3.0,0.2],
  mode: 'lines',
  line:{
    color:'black'
  },
  type: 'scatter'
};


  var layout = {
    font:{
      // Text size and color
      size:16,
      family:'helvetica',
      color: "white"
    },
    annotations: arrow(),
    xaxis:  {
      side: 'bottom',
      orientation: "right"
    },
    yaxis: {
      autosize: true,
      tickfont: "white",
      ticksuffix: "%",
      // Y axis scale
      autorange: false,
      range :[-20,20]
    },
    // Graph position
    margin: {
    l: 90,
    r: 90,
    b: 120,
    t: 20,
    pad: 10
  },
    // Graph background colors
    paper_bgcolor: "transparent", 
    plot_bgcolor:"transparent", 
  };

var data = [trace1, trace2];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv',data,layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh dam, my trace1 had braces+curly braces around the values, which worked for only the bar, but made it dissappear when the linegraph was called.